# Cual seria la solución para este error de fetch_Object() en php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mariadb

La cuestión es que cuando intento ejecutar el código, me lanza el siguiente error:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() 
    on 
    boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\ajax\categoria.php:38 Stack trace: #0 
    {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\ajax\categoria.php on line 
    38
```

Aqui el codigo correspondiente a categoria.php

```
    require_once "../modelos/Categoria.php";

    $categoria=new Categoria();

    $idcategoria=isset($_POST["idcategoria"])
    limpiarCadena($_POST["idcategoria"]):"";
    $nombre=isset($_POST["nombre"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["nombre"]):"";
    $descripcion=isset($_POST["descripcion"])? 
    limpiarCadena($_POST["descripcion"]):"";

    switch ($_GET["op"]) {
    case 'guardaryeditar':
    if (empty($idcategoria)) {
        $rspta=$categoria->insertar($nombre,$descripcion);
            echo $rspta ? "Categoria registrada" : "Categoria no se pudo 
            registrar";
    }else{
        $rspta=$categoria->editar($idcategoria, $nombre, $descripcion);
            echo $rspta ? "Categoria actualizada" : "Categoria no se pudo 
            actualizar";
        }
        break;
    case 'desactivar':
        $rspta=$categoria->desactivar($idcategoria);
            echo $rspta ? "Categoria Desactivada" : "Categoria no se pudo 
            Desactivar";
        break;
    case 'activar':
        $rspta=$categoria->activar($idcategoria);
            echo $rspta ? "Categoria Activada" : "Categoria no se pudo 
            Activar";
        break;
    case 'mostrar':
        $rspta=$categoria->mostrar($idcategoria);
        echo json_encode($rspta);
        break;
     case 'listar':
        $rspta=$categoria->listar();
        //Vamos a declarar un Array
        $data= Array();

        while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()) {
            $data[]=array(
            "0"=>$reg->idcategoria,
            "1"=>$reg->nombre,
            "2"=>$reg->descripcion,
            "3"=>$reg->condicion
            );
        }
        $results = array(
        "sEcho"=>1,
        "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),
        "aaData"=>$data
        );
        echo json_encode($results);
        break;
     default:
        # code...
        break;
     }
```

Ya he buscado en todos lados una solución apropiada pero en ninguno tuve éxito, por lo que me gustaría la ayuda de alguien que sepa manejar bien los que seria PHP.

Saludos Cordiales.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Me puedes decir como lo solucionaste, me aparece el mismo error y aún no encuentro la solución

Answer (score 0):

Ese error es porque tienes como resultado un booleano `false`

Para evitar ese mensaje de error lo puedes comprobar de esta manera:

```
while ( $rspta && $reg = $rspta->fetch_object() ) { ... }
```

Comment: Ya me muestra el resultado pero me sigue mandando un mensaje de error.           Notice: Undefined variable: reg in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema\ajax\categoria.php on line 38
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":0,"iTotalDisplayRecords":0,"aaData":[]}

Comment: Perdón me equivocado... edito la respuesta

Comment: Ya me funciona, muchas gracias. Black Sheep

Comment: No hay de que... me alegro ;)

Comment: @ArielPeralta004 si te sirvio la respuesta puedes marcarla como respuesta aceptada ✓ ✓

Answer (score 0):

Hola la unica solución es en el ajax de listar colocar en cada uno de los arrays la funcion utf8_decode.

Ejemplo:

```
    case 'listar':
    $rspta=$categoria->listar();
    //Vamos a declarar un Array
    $data= Array();

    while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()){
        $data[]=array(
        "0"=>$reg->idcategoria,
        "1"=>$reg->utf8_decode(nombre),
        "2"=>$reg->utf8_decode(descripcion),
        "3"=>utf8_decode($reg->condicion)
    }
     $results = array(
    "sEcho"=>1,
    "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),
    "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),
    "aaData"=>$data
    );
    echo json_encode($results);
    break;
 default:
    # code...
    break;
 }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).